# Unitary Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

This question has stumped me for DAYS...
The question:

Find a unitary matrix that maps ($1,-1,1$) to ($\sqrt{3},0,0$) and ($1,2,-2$) to ($0,3,0$).

**What have you tried?**
I have realized that this unitary matrix will have to be 3-by-3, and the equation, in matrix form, will look like this:
U*X=B, where X is given by:
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \\ 1 & -2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
and B is given by: \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{3} & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}

From there, I realized two things:

1. This unitary transformation is changing coordinates from the usual basis to the following basis: {$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot(1,-1,1), (\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{-2}{3})$}
2. This looks like an example of what I might get by solving $A=Q*R$ for $R$. All we need to do is set $Q'=U, R=B, A=X$.

From those points, I have tried to perform the $QR$ decomposition of $A$ (or $X$ in this case) and my $R$ doesn't equal $B$. 
Also, I have tried to add a vector to the column space of $X$ by computing the nullspace of $X'$. In doing so, I get the vector $(0,1,1)$, which I append to $X$. Since I know that this vector is orthogonal to the other two vectors, $(1,-1,1)$, $(1,2,-2)$, and $U$ is an invertible matrix, I therefore reason that $U((0,1,1))$ must be orthogonal to $U((1,-1,1))$ and $U((1,2,-2))$. I try to play on the fact that B contains the lengths of the column vectors of $X$, and use this to justify appending $(0,0,\sqrt{2})$ to the column space of $B$. I try to solve this, and I get:
$$U= \frac{1}{6}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}4*\sqrt{3} & -\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3} \\ 6 & 3 & -3 \\ 0 & 3*\sqrt{2} & 3*\sqrt{2} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$. If I ask WolframAlpha if this matrix is unitary (its inverse is its transpose), the answer is NO: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%28%7B%7Bsqrt%283%29%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C3%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Csqrt%282%29%7D%7D.inverse%28%7B%7B1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B-1%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C-2%2C1%7D%7D%29%29 . In fact, I can check this in my head by computing the length of the first row vector and seeing that it is not $1$.

Is there any other way I could solve this problem??

Comment: @Zeonatra how did you do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to the problem was good and if it was possible for a unitary matrix to map the first two vectors to the second two vectors then your approach for finding the unitary matrix would have worked.

Answer (score 3):

A unitary matrix $U$ satisfies $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle Ux,Uy \rangle$. The inner product of $(1,-1,1)$ and $(1,2,-2)$ is $-3$, but the inner product of $(\sqrt{3},0,0)$ and $(0,3,0)$ is $0$.

Comment: So, I cannot use that idea. This would answer the first question: does such a transformation even exist? Thank you for your swift response.